# Need help in Sales Order for "RC" order type

Tags: acumatica

Need help in "RC" order type. The scenario is - an item has been sold to a customer from "Wholesale" warehouse which has serial number.  Now customer returned the item and we want to receive it in another warehouse "Retail".

We have created sales order with "RC" order type, by default warehouse at line level is picking up the original warehouse "Wholesale" and also has serial number allocated, now the issue is, if we change the warehouse from "Wholesale" to "Retail" serial number in allocations popup is getting cleared, if we forcefully entered the number and created receipt(shipment) the line item in shipment screen does not pick up the serial number.

Could any help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

At the sales order level, even though it is picking the warehouse and serial number for RC orders it will disappear when you refresh or modify the line.

This happens when the serial number does not exist in the warehouse because it is already sold, so the system does not allow you to allocate. I think that functionality might be tied to the Inventory Item Lot/Serial Class Assignment Method (when received/when used).

A possible workaround is changing the warehouse to Retail in the RC order (without serial number). When you create the receipt shipment, in the shipment enter the required serial number and it should accept the serial number in shipment.